# Getting Select Dropdown Info from a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a button to grab select option values that are within the same row. If I were to add a function to the select dropdown, I get these values:

[image]

When I add another button to grab these values, I can't quite get the same information. It looks like this:

[image]

The getValue is just the variable holding the information. If I do getValue[0], it grabs the 0: select#manufacturer_1... but I want to replicate the first image where it has all of those values at the base level.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="manufactor-selector-dropdown">
        <option>Manufactor1</option>
        <option>Manufactor2</option>
        <option>Manufactor3</option>
        ...
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <button>Select Values </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

javascript:

```
function(n) {
   var getValue = $(n).parents('tr').find('td .manufactor-selector-dropdown');
   var getSelectedValue = getValue.val();
}
```

Comment: So there are at least two buttons mentioned, but you only have one in your html. Where are the other button(s)? Do they use the same function? How are those function(s) called?

Comment: How are you calling the function? It has no name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am partly guessing as to what your intended result is supposed to be. Maybe the following is helpful?

```js
function getVals(ev){
  var getAllOptionValues = $(ev.target).parents('tr').find('td .manufactor-selector-dropdown option')
      .map((i,o)=>o.value).get();
  console.log(getAllOptionValues);
}

$("button").click(getVals)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="manufactor-selector-dropdown">
        <option>Manufactor1</option>
        <option>Manufactor2</option>
        <option>Manufactor3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <button>Select Values </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="manufactor-selector-dropdown">
        <option>Supplier1</option>
        <option>Supplier2</option>
        <option>Supplier3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <button>Select Values </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I changed your "function" quite a bit. It now looks for the parent element of the clicked button, then goes down and collects all options of the element with class "manufactor-selector-dropdown option" that is under a "td" element. with the jQuery method `.map()` I then extract all their values and convert the jQuery object into an array with `.get()`.